# A Reset button and a bookmark button in mapkit in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, mapkit

I am currently working on an application involving mapkit. I would like to add a reset button on the view which resets the view to its default view when you open the program, or better still, the mapkit resets itself when you open and close the app.

The code i have used to set the initial region is as follows:

```
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 54.049929;
region.center.longitude = -4.54834;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 4.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 4.5;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you want to reload the map to your initial setup?

Comment: yes exactly what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the Location of your map 
In .h file

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
```

When setting initial Region

```
location.latitude = 54.049929;
location.longitude = -4.54834;
```

In your Reset Button

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = location.latitude
region.center.longitude = location.longitude;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 4.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 4.5;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

So, are you trying to figure out how to actually add the button to the view and link it to a method in the code?

The code itself within the method would just be the same as you used for your initial setup, as indicated by BuildSucceded above ...

You should just add a button to the toolbar/navbar(if you have one), and link it to a "resetMap()" method.